# Why this sql query takes minutes to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

Firstly this query worked fine with single database but when I used different databases ( product and pms_history  ) in it, it started taking minutes to be executed.

```
SELECT SUM(ppi.`key_closing_balance`) FROM `pms_history`.`pool_product_income` ppi,`pms`.product p
WHERE ppi.`pool_id`=$P{poolId} AND ppi.`product_id`=p.`id`
AND ((p.`line` BETWEEN 155 AND 460) OR (p.`line`=2855)) AND p.`account_type`='PL'

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(ppi.`key_closing_balance`) FROM pms_history.`pool_product_income` ppi,pms.product p
WHERE ppi.`pool_id`=$P{poolId} AND ppi.`product_id`=p.`id`
AND ((p.`line`=35)) AND p.`account_type`='PL'

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(ppi.`key_closing_balance`) FROM pms_history.`pool_product_income` ppi,pms.product p
WHERE ppi.`pool_id`=$P{poolId} AND ppi.`product_id`=p.`id`
AND ((p.`line`=39)) AND p.`account_type`='PL'

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(ppi.`key_closing_balance`) FROM pms_history.`pool_product_income` ppi,pms.product p
WHERE ppi.`pool_id`=$P{poolId} AND ppi.`product_id`=p.`id`
AND ((p.`line` BETWEEN 705 AND 715)) AND p.`account_type`='PL'

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(ppi.`key_closing_balance`) FROM pms_history.`pool_product_income` ppi,pms.product p
WHERE ppi.`pool_id`=$P{poolId} AND ppi.`product_id`=p.`id`
AND ((p.`line` BETWEEN 60 AND 124 ) OR (p.`line` BETWEEN 2195 AND 2225)) AND p.`account_type`='PL';
```

Comment: Step 1, run each of the selects stand-alone to find the problem one!

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN SELECT....` and examine (and post if needed) the results. I suspect that these `UNION ALL` commands are creating lots and lots of rows that need to be managed...

Comment: I run explain select, it didn't gave proper result and same problem exists in each select.  @Ken Y-N

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation. Then you can do the whole query at once, without the `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT SUM(case when (p.`line` BETWEEN 155 AND 460) OR (p.`line`=2855) then ppi.`key_closing_balance` end),
       SUM(case when (p.`line` = 35) then ppi.`key_closing_balance` end),
       SUM(case when (p.`line` = 39) then ppi.`key_closing_balance` end),
       SUM(case when (p.`line` BETWEEN 705 AND 715) then ppi.`key_closing_balance` end),
       SUM(case when (p.`line` BETWEEN 60 AND 124 ) OR (p.`line` BETWEEN 2195 AND 2225) then ppi.`key_closing_balance` end) 
FROM `pms_history`.`pool_product_income` ppi 
  JOIN `pms`.product p ON ppi.`product_id` = p.`id`
WHERE ppi.`pool_id` = $P{poolId}
  AND p.`account_type` = 'PL'
```

Did also switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: This way works a little good but doesn't return me sum of all in single column. I receive five times sum in horizontal manner where as I need single column having total of all sum. @jarlh

Comment: That's just a display issue! You can easily fix it in an above layer!

Comment: Can u plz suggest me how to display it in single column? I tried it but couldn't achieve. @jarlh

Comment: Sorry, I don't know MySQL that well, or php.

Comment: It's ok, Thank you very much. @jarlh